# How to use importhtml in Google Sheets to import tables from multiple URLS coninuously in same spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

`URL1`, `URL2`, `URL3` all contain one table each.
I am currently importing each in different sheets.
Is there anyway to import them continuously in the same spreadsheet?

**Update1**: The number of rows in tables vary everyday, so I have to do it manually. I would like to know if there is a way to combine two `importhtml` functions with query or concat?
Something like `=importhtml (url1, table,2) & importhtml (url2, table,2)`

**Update2**: I have attached sample file link here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VdFMzRTwcaFAglGNpqvzGytdz_mqohtxGgAywKlLi0U/edit?usp=sharing
In `A1` there's one table and in `I1` there is another.
This is stock market data so it changes everyday. I would like to know if there is a way to combine the formulas?

Comment: Please use a test sheet with examples and expected results. Your question is way too general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **EDIT**

*(following OP's [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63139607/how-to-use-importhtml-in-google-sheets-to-import-tables-from-multiple-urls-conin#comment111653740_63139999))*

> *This worked perfectly. Is there anyway to loose the header row of the second table...*

Please inclose the `IMPORTHTML` functions in a [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

```
={QUERY(IMPORTHTML("xxx","table",1), "where Col1 is not null",1);
  QUERY(IMPORTHTML("yyy","table",1), "where Col1 is not null offset 1",0)}
```

Please notice that in the second `QUERY` we use `offset 1",0`.
This will eliminate the headers of the second table.

***PRO TIP***
Since you now have everything in queries, you can also take advantage of all the many, so very flexible query properties/clauses like [`select`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#select), [`order by`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#order-by), [`group-by`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#group-by) etc.

---

> I am currently importing each in different sheets, is there anyway to import them continuously in the same spreadsheet?

Most likely yes. It highly depends on the formulas you use and the structure of the tables.
If they all have the same amount of columns you can probably create an array like

```
={IMPORTHTML("xxx","table",1);
IMPORTHTML("yyy","table",1)}
IMPORTHTML("zzzz","table",1)}
```

The above formula will stack the tables one on top of the other.

*(hard to give a definite answer without further info and expected results)*

Comment: importhtml command imports table but everyday the length of table varies. is there anyway to combine two importhtml commands?

Comment: I see your sheet but still fail to understand your **expected results**.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Is there anyway to loose the header row of the second table...